# displaying the days of the month in PHP and comparing them with dates in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with correctly generating the days of the month, e.g. from 2018-10-01 to 2018-10-31 and checking if every day generated in the "for" loop is in the MySql database.

I can generate days but during the condition of date comparison from the generated loop with data from the database it displays only records from the database and how it needs to insert empty in the blank records Add date to create errors.

my code :

```
 $conn = dbManager::getConnection();


   $tr = 1;

for($tr; $tr < $day; $tr++){

  $dt = new DateTime($start);

  $msc = $dt->format('m');

      switch ($msc) {
        case '1':
         $m = '1';
          break;
        case '2':
         $m = '2';
          break;
        case '3':
         $m = '3';
          break;
        case '4':
          $m = '4';
          break;
        case '5':
          $m = '5';
          break;
        case '6':
         $m = '6';
          break;
        case '7':
         $m = '7';
          break;
        case '8':
          $m = '8';
          break;
        case '9':
          $m = '9';
          break;
        case '10':
          $m = '10';
          break;
        case '11':
          $m = '11';
          break;
        case '12':
          $m = '12';
          break;

      }

         if($m < 10){
          $mc = '0'.$m;
         }else{
          $mc = $m;
         }

         if($tr < 10){ 
          $tr = '0'.$tr;
         }else{
          $tr = $tr;
         }


   $data = date('Y-'.$mc.'-'.$tr);

   echo "<tr><td>".$data."</td><td  style='vertical-align:middle;'>";


   $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM open ")or die(mysqli_error());


      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){       

           $Start = $row['Start'];
           $End = $row['End'];

           $dtb = new DateTime($Start);
           $dtb_e = new DateTime($End);
           $dtb_e->add(new DateInterval('PT1H'));

           $w= $dtb->format('Y-m-d');
           $ts = $dtb->format('H'); 
           $te = $dtb_e->format('H');



          if($w == $data){


             for($h=1;$h<24;$h++){

                 if($h >= $ts && $h <= $te){
                   if($w < date('Y-m-d')){ 
                    $color ='gray';
                   }else{
                    $color = 'green';
                   }

                   echo '<p style="display:inline;padding:5px; border:1px solid ;background:'.$color.';color:#fff;border-radius: 5px;margin-right:5px;">'.$h.':00</p>';
                 }else{
                  $color = 'gray';

                  echo '<p style="display:inline;padding:5px; border:1px solid ;background:'.$color.';color:#fff;border-radius: 5px;margin-right:5px;">'.$h.':00</p>';
                 }
              }


              if($data >= date('Y-m-d')){ 

               echo '<div style="display:inline;text-align:rigth;margin-left:35px;"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success"  href="edit_termin.php?Start='.$row['Start'].'&End='.$row['End'].'&ID='.$row['ID'].'" role="button">Edytuj</a><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"  href="del_open.php?Start='.$row['Start'].'&End='.$row['End'].'&ID='.$row['ID'].'" role="button">Usuń</a></div>';
              }else{ 
                echo '<div style="display:inline;text-align:rigth;margin-left:35px;"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success disabled"  href="edit_termin.php?Start='.$row['Start'].'&End='.$row['End'].'&ID='.$row['ID'].'" role="button">Edytuj</a><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger disabled"  href="del_open.php?Start='.$row['Start'].'&End='.$row['End'].'&ID='.$row['ID'].'" role="button">Usuń</a></div>';
              }

              if($data != $data){
                        $dodaj = '<div style="display:inline;text-align:rigth;margin-left:35px;"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success"  href="edit_termin.php?Start='.$data.'" role="button">Dodaj</a></div>';
                         echo $dodaj;
              }else{
                echo 'x';
              }

          }else{
              if($data != $data){
                        $dodaj = '<div style="display:inline;text-align:rigth;margin-left:35px;"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success"  href="edit_termin.php?Start='.$data.'" role="button">Dodaj</a></div>';
                         echo $dodaj;
              }else{
                echo 'x';
              }
            echo  '<div style="display:inline;text-align:rigth;margin-left:35px;"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success"  href="edit_termin.php?Start='.$data.'" role="button">Dodaj</a></div>';  


          }


      }  

}
 echo "</td></tr>";
```

below result:

[generated days without a button add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCRUH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will get you going. The idea is to fetch all the results at once so you are able to check if the date is already in the database or not:

```
$conn = dbManager::getConnection();
$tr = 1;

$dt = new DateTime();
$msc = $dt->format('m');
$mc = str_pad($msc, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

// You should limit your results to the working month
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM open ")or die(mysqli_error());

$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$db_dates = array_column($rows, 'Start');
$db_dates = array_map(function($v) { 
  $d = new DateTime($v); 
  return $d->format('Y-m-d');
}, $db_dates);

for($tr; $tr < $day; $tr++){
  $tr = str_pad($tr, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

  $data = date('Y-'.$mc.'-'.$tr);

  // Check if current date is not in the db result
  $target_date = array_search($data, $db_dates);

  if ($target_date === FALSE) {
      // Add your buttons
  } else {
    // Column and map operations keep the indexes, access your record
    $row = $rows[$target_date];
      // Rest of your logic in here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**msg** thanks for the help. I modified it according to your hints and works showing the button in the right place but it takes only the hours from the database fields from the last record. :( np.Start 2018-10-05 09:00 End 2018-10-05 20:00) script shows only these hours for each record found in the database and not those hours that are assigned to a given date .. Where can I make a mistake ?

```
 $tr=1;

            for($tr; $tr < $day; $tr++){

              $dt = new DateTime($start);

                $msc = $dt->format('m');

                    switch ($msc) {
                      case '1':
                       $m = '1';
                        break;
                      case '2':
                       $m = '2';
                        break;
                      case '3':
                       $m = '3';
                        break;
                      case '4':
                        $m = '4';
                        break;
                      case '5':
                        $m = '5';
                        break;
                      case '6':
                       $m = '6';
                        break;
                      case '7':
                       $m = '7';
                        break;
                      case '8':
                        $m = '8';
                        break;
                      case '9':
                        $m = '9';
                        break;
                      case '10':
                        $m = '10';
                        break;
                      case '11':
                        $m = '11';
                        break;
                      case '12':
                        $m = '12';
                        break;

                    }

                       if($m < 10){
                        $mc = '0'.$m;
                       }else{
                        $mc = $m;
                       }

                       if($tr < 10){ 
                        $tr = '0'.$tr;
                       }else{
                        $tr = $tr;
                       }

              //$dt = new DateTime($start);
              //$msc = $dt->format('m');

              // $mc = $nsc; //strpad($msc, 2, '0');
              //strpad($tr, 2, '0');

              $data = date('Y-'.$mc.'-'.$tr);

              echo '<tr><td>'.$data.'</td><td>';

              // You should limit your results to the working month
              $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM open ".$month." ")or die(mysqli_error());

              $rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
              $db_dates = array_column($rows, 'Start');
              $db_dates = array_map(function($data) { 
                $d = new DateTime($data); 
                return $d->format('Y-m-d');
              }, $db_dates);



              // Check if current date is not in the db result
              $target_date = array_search($data, $db_dates);

              if ($target_date !== FALSE) {
                  // Add your buttons

                foreach ($rows as $key) {

                  $Start = $key['Start'];
                  $End = $key['End'];
                  $id = $key['ID'];
                }


                             $str = $key['Start'];
                             $ed = $key['End'];

                             $dtb = new DateTime($str);
                             $dtb_e = new DateTime($ed);
                             $dtb_e->add(new DateInterval('PT1H'));

                             $w= $dtb->format('Y-m-d');
                             $ts = $dtb->format('H'); 
                             $te = $dtb_e->format('H');



                               for($h=1;$h<24;$h++){

                                 if($h >= $ts && $h <= $te){

                                   if($w < date('Y-m-d')){ 
                                    $color ='gray';
                                   }else{
                                    $color = 'green';
                                   }

                                   echo '<p style="display:inline;padding:5px; border:1px solid ;background:'.$color.';color:#fff;border-radius: 5px;margin-right:5px;">'.$h.':00</p>';

                                 }else{

                                  $color = 'gray';
                                  echo '<p style="display:inline;padding:5px; border:1px solid ;background:'.$color.';color:#fff;border-radius: 5px;margin-right:5px;">'.$h.':00</p>';
                                 }
                              }

                              //--------------------------------------

                              if($data >= date('Y-m-d')){ 

                                 //-------------------------
                                 $dst = $data.' '.$ts.':00';
                                 $den = $data.' '.$te.':00';

                                 //echo "SELECT * FROM open WHERE Start >= '".$dst."' AND End <= '".$den."' ";
                                 $res = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM open WHERE Start >= '".$dst."' AND End <= '".$den."' ");

                                 while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                                  $idr = $r['ID']; //ID record


                               echo '<td><div style="display:inline;text-align:rigth;margin-left:35px;"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success"  href="edit_termin.php?Start='.$dst.'&End='.$den.'&ID='.$idr.'" role="button">Edutuj</a><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"  href="del_open.php?Start='.$dst.'&End='.$den.'&ID='.$idr.'" role="button">Usuń</a></div></td>';
                                 }

                              }else{ 
                                echo '<td><div style="display:inline;text-align:rigth;margin-left:35px;"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success disabled"  href="edit_termin.php?Start='.$row['Start'].'&End='.$row['End'].'&ID='.$idr.'" role="button">Edytuj</a><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger disabled"  href="del_open.php?Start='.$row['Start'].'&End='.$row['End'].'&ID='.$row['ID'].'" role="button">Usuń</a></div></td>';
                              }

              } else {
                // Column and map operations keep the indexes, access your record
                $row = $rows[$target_date];
                  // Rest of your logic in here
                 if($data >= date('Y-m-d')){
                     echo  '<td><div style="display:inline;text-align:rigth;margin-left:35px;"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success"  href="form_terminarz.php?Start='.$data.'" role="button">Dodaj termin</a></div></td>'; 
                  }else{
                     echo  '<td><div style="display:inline;text-align:rigth;margin-left:35px;"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success disabled"  href="form_terminarz.php?Start='.$data.'" role="button">Dodaj termin</a></div></td>'; 
                  } 
              }

              echo '<td></tr>';
            }
```